# On the Logic of Logics

Tags: logic, proof-theory, natural-deduction

I am teaching myself logic (from various sources), and I was viewing this video: https://youtu.be/IOiZatlZtGU. I had a few questions about 'proving' statements about logic in logic.

- At 16:50 (https://youtu.be/IOiZatlZtGU?t=996), the speaker talks about how we can *prove* that Gentzen's system of Natural Deduction is consistent (that is, there is no proof of ⊥). The argument goes as follows: "the sub-formula property says a proof of ⊥ should have ⊥ and only sub-formulas of ⊥. Since there is no sub-formula of ⊥, there is no proof of ⊥".
- This argument seems quite simple, and it *seems to me (perhaps incorrectly)* that one should be able to formalize this argument (about Natural Deduction) formally using Natural Deduction itself.

  - However, this seems to contradict Gödel's second incompleteness theorem (that is, a (*powerful  enough*) logical system cannot prove its own consistency).
  - Clearly, I've made a mistake somewhere. Perhaps:

    1. Natural Deduction is not *powerful enough*, and therefore can prove its own consistency?
    2. Natural Deduction cannot *encode itself* / 'talk about itself'?
    3. We cannot formalize the argument presented in the video in Natural Deduction.
  - I think at least one of these 3 should be incorrect. I am curious to know what they are.
- I think, more generally, I am curious about how one formally proves 'things' (like consistency, etc.) about logics themselves:

  - If *L1* is a logic, and we want to formally reason about *L1*, I think we'd need to *encode* *L1* (all its axioms and rules of inference) in another (equally or more powerful?) logic *L2*, where we can make statements like '*L1* is consistent', etc. Is this true? What makes a logic 'more powerful' than another logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are discussing Gentzen’s natural deductive system as a mathematical object itself, we must be in a suitably expressive metatheory such as Peano Arithmetic or ZFC. We can then prove in that theory (using induction, a fairly powerful mathematical tool) that natural deduction cannot prove $\bot$.

It is not clear how one could encode the statement “Natural deduction is consistent” in pure first-order logic, which is the system natural deduction uses. Instead, one must consider a particular first-order theory like Peano Arithmetic, think about its intended model, and then perform definitions which, in the intended model, define the statement “natural deduction is consistent”. This is a fundamentally metamathematical task.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this sense, would we say that PA / ZFC is 'stronger' than FOL?

Comment: "Instead, one must consider a particular first-order theory like Peano Arithmetic, think about its intended model, and then perform definitions which, in the intended model"

To understand this statement a little better, let's consider Godel's proof, where we use Peano Arithmetic to make statements about Peano Arithmetic itself. 

Does this mean that:
1. "The particular first order theory" is PA?
2. "The intended model" is also PA?

Comment: Strictly speaking, we do not use Peano Arithmetic to “make statements about itself”. We use Peano arithmetic to make statements which, when interpreted in the canonical model $\mathbb{N}$, are statements about itself.